# How to output $.get() method JQuery with Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I could not output the data created in Flask to JQuery in a Html page.

I am testing $.get() method in JQuery with Flask. The task is to return a String to a Html page and display it as paragraph. But the result cannot be displayed. Can someone shed a light on this issue. Thanks!

Here is the code in Flask

```
from flask import request, jsonify, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
@app.route('/hello', methods=["GET"])
def hello():
    return jsonify('<h1>Hello Flask !!!</h1>')
```

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Events </title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#btnGet").click(function()
            {

                //$.get('https://httpbin.org/get',
                $.get('http://localhost:5000/hello',
                    function(data)
                    {
                        $("#getInfo").text(data)
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btnGet">Click to Get Info </button>
    <p  id="getInfo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? Since you're fetching JSON, so you should probably be using $.getJSON. That will parse the returned data as JSON and hand you back an object. You can also try adding [.fail()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to the end of the $.getJSON request to see the error object.

Comment: @NickK9, I tried with return 'Hello Flask !!!', it did not work either. The error is that I am expecting <<p  id="getInfo">Hello Flask !!</p> but nothing shows up.   While when I open http://localhost:5000/ in a browser, I can see 'Hello Flask !!' there. So my understanding is that ```$.get('http://localhost:5000/hello',
                    function(data)
                    {
                        $("#getInfo").text(data)
                    });``` is not capturing or parsing the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

As new to web programming, after hours trial and error, finally found out that I am not placing the html under static folder and run it in Eclipse Environment. After open it up in http://localhost:5000/static/test.html then it works as expected.